# Angular2 deployment - How to automatically modify the reference to styles.bundle.css in index.html

Tags: css, angular, deployment, styles

In my Angular2 application, Index.html file I have the following line.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

When I deploy to the server, I am using "ng build" command. This generates a set of files and converts my "styles.css" file to "styles.bundle.css".

But it fails to change the reference in the index.html file. After deploying it on the server, I am opening the index.html file and changing it like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.bundle.css">
```

My question is,

1. Is there an automated technique where the "ng build" command can fix all the references to the new style file name?
2. Is there a way to tell "ng build" command not to bundle my styles?

Comment: You should use `ng build` to create the production deployment, `ng serve` is for local testing.

Comment: I am using "ng build". I have edited the "original question". Sorry.

Comment: Are you using the files from `dist/`? Which version of the CLI? How are you deploying it? Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: I am using angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24. I am copying all the contents from the "dist" folder to my "server" as is. When I issue the "ng build" command I use the base href option like this (ng build -base-href "/MainApp/ClientTool/") .

Answer (score 0):

If you generated the project with Angular CLI, your src/index.html should not have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.bundle.css">`

The ng build command takes the css file that you specified in the angular-cli.json in the section styles and creates the tag `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.bundle.css">` in the file dist/index.html automatically. 
You shouldn't need to change it manually.

Comment: I agree. For some unknown reason it's not changing for me. After I publish, I am manually changing it.